# Combinations of unique sentences

Tags: combinatorics

Say you are making a sentence with four words and each position has a set number of words you can choose from (word1 + word2 + word3 + word4 = sentence). For instance, the first word you have eight choices/possibilities, second word = four choices, third word = four choices, and fourth word = eight possibilities. What is the number of different sentences you could make with these options? And let’s assume that all the words work in their designated positions with each other, even though it might not be the case in the real world.

I think it has to involve combinations vs permutations because order doesn’t necessarily matter, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works here is the [Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). You multiply the amounts of choices you have for each word. In your example

$$8\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot 8 = 1024.$$

Here's another example. If

- for the $w_1$ you have the 3 choices: $\{\text{maths, biology, geography}\}$
- for $w_2$ you have the 2 choices: $\{\text{is, isn't}\}$
- for $w_3$ just 1 choice: $\{\text{fun}\}$.

Can you form all the $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 6$ possible sentences? It's quite obvious that independently of any other subject you can say that any subject ($3$) either is or isn't ($2$) fun ($1$).